# Export Visualization(s) to Excel with a click of a Button Q

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have 5 visualizations that are tables. Where would I find examples of creating a Button that would export these data sets to 1 Excel file with multiple tabs or anything remotely similar?  Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure this kind of functionality doesn't currently exist within Power BI.

Comment: I would rebuild the tables using Power BI's Analyze in Excel feature.